# How to detect moving to different domain page?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a ruby on rails app and I want to detect user moving to different domain page
while in model creating wizard.
I stored model-data to DB at first-step of wizard and  redirect_to second-step of wizard.
And I want to destroy it if user moving to different domain page while in second-step.

I already find a way to hook onbeforeload event to show warning to user.
But I want to warn it only if user moving to different domain page but not to third-step.
And if user want to moving different domain page then I want to destroy stored data.

What is a best solution to do this? Is there any way to detect where user want to go?

EDIT:
In second-step I want to create model from user upload file(ajax upload with jQuery File Uploader) and associate with first-step's model. So if I can get which id will assign to first-step's model then I can easily associate with it. This is why I want to store data in first-step.

And I don't want to expire unfineshed model until user explicitly leaving wizard.
Then can I detect whether user still opening wizard and just stopping very long time or 
already leaving wizard page?
(I want to build app just like a desktop application so user can have unsaved file until explicity leaving wizard on multiple browser window)

Answer (score 0):

That's is not possible. Once your page is unloaded you cannot do anything else. If the user is loading another domain page then that domain has control over the page, not you.

What you should do is store the data of the wizard pages not in db but on session state or even in a cookie, this is the good practice. Then, when user reach the final step of the wizard you read the data from cookie/session and write to db at once.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot determine the user's intended destination within the `onbeforeunload` event, or any other. You also can't stop a user's request to load another page and instead redirect them to some `destroy` action before sending them off on their way.

If you are content with storing data into the database on each step as the user progresses through your wizard, you can look into setting up a cron job to run a rake task you create which can go through and delete incomplete wizards that are older than a certain age.

The cron *(or equivalent)* actually is something I'd consider doing even if you *could* detect a user leaving your site.